# How to remove one-off increases in value

Tags: r, dplyr, outliers

I'm working with time series data on a variable that generally increases slowly over time. Very simplified example:

```
df <- data.frame(index=1:8, value = c(rep(0.25, 3),1.95,0.25,rep(0.5,3)))

 index value
     1  0.25
     2  0.25
     3  0.25
     4  1.95
     5  0.25
     6  0.50
     7  0.50
     8  0.50
```

A recurring feature of the dataset is what happens at index 4: the value spikes upward then immediately comes back down again. I want to remove those values. (There are also points in my dataset where the value makes a small increase followed by a small decrease some time later, but I want to keep those.)

I have found a way of removing the values, by using `diff` to calculate the change from the previous value, then turning the data frame upside down, using `diff` again to calculate the change from the next value and removing rows where the two diffs are the same, but that seems like the least efficient process ever:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(diffprev = diff(value) %>% c(0, .)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(variable)) %>% 
  mutate(diffnext = diff(value) %>% c(0, .)) %>% 
  filter(diffprev == 0 | diffprev != diffnext)
```

I realise that if the spike in value happened at index 5 rather than 4 this wouldn't work but in the full dataset this is so unlikely that unless there's a simple fix I'm not going to worry about it. But what would be a better way of going about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
df %>% filter(lag(value) != lead(value) | (value - lag(value)) %in% c(0, NA))
```

You might also be interested in the `lag` and `lead` functions from `dplyr`.

Edit: thanks @Frank for a couple modifications

Comment: Yeah, I prefer this answer to my way, but I'll leave mine up as it shows a way of building on the OP's approach. You could change `==0` to `%in% c(0,NA)` to keep the first row.

Comment: Brilliant. I've had loads of problems where I've thought "But I wish I could filter on the row above that value." Lead and lag look like what I was looking for all along.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to rearrange. The first diff column you make contains all the info you need:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(diffprev = diff(value) %>% c(0, .)) %>%
  filter(diffprev == 0 | diffprev != -lead(diffprev) ) %>%
  select(-diffprev)
```

which gives

```
  variable value
1        1  0.25
2        2  0.25
3        3  0.25
4        5  0.25
5        6  0.50
6        7  0.50
7        8  0.50
```